# How to show only user assigned contents in his dashboard?

Tags: 7, views, users

I have more than 270 pages in my website.

There are some Content Creators, Content Editors, Reviewers and Publisher.
I have assigned each user a different role. 
Each user can view, edit and publish each others' pages.

I wanted to create something like;
When user logged in with his user name and password, first he can see only his own created/assigned content pages when he clicks on content tab.

How to show only user assigned contents in his dashboard?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! In the same way you filter the view to show published nodes, you can filter the view to show only the nodes created by the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

In your view simply follow these steps:

1. Click the **Advance Tab** under the **RELATIONSHIPS** add a new relationship  `Content:Author`
   [image: preview]
2. Keep the **Identifier** as it is, but remember to check the `Require this relationship` option.
   [image: require-this-relationship]
3. Now, under **FILTER CRITERIA** add a new filter `User: Current` and check the `Is the logged in user` as `Yes`
   [image: is-the-user-logged-in]

## The exported code:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'article';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Article';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Article';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Content: Author */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'article' => 'article',
);
/* Filter criterion: User: Current */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['id'] = 'uid_current';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['field'] = 'uid_current';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['relationship'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['expose']['operator_id'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['expose']['label'] = 'Is the logged in user';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['expose']['operator'] = 'uid_current_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['expose']['identifier'] = 'uid_current';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['uid_current']['expose']['required'] = TRUE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'article';
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In Views, under the Advanced Tab, create a relationship to content:author, required.

Set a Filter Criteria to User:Current

This should restrict the View to content authored by the currently logged in user.